# Write a Java program that prompts for a number and counts down from that number

Tags: java

I have to write a code where it prompts the user to input a number, and it should count down from the number to 0. I am given this:
There are three required functions, main(), doCountDown(), and
waitASec(). Optionally, a fourth function will perform user
interaction.
So far, this is what I have. There are no errors and the code runs. However, the countdown does not stop at 0, it continuously counts down into negative numbers. I am not sure where to go from here.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Code {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Count down how many seconds? ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();
        doCountDown(num);
    }
    public static void doCountDown(int num){
        for(int i=num;i<=num;i--){
            System.out.println(i);
            waitASec();
        }
    }
    private static void waitASec() {
        long t = new Date().getTime();
        long t1=t+1000;
        for(;t<t1;) {
            t = new Date().getTime();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Change `for(int i=num;i<=num;i--)` to `for(int i=num;i>=0;i--)`

Comment: well, if it is not stopping, check the condition: `for (<initial>; <condition>; <increment>)` - <condition> is the condition to execute the iteration. The loop will terminate when this is **false**

Comment: For the waitASec method, you can just use Thread.sleep(1000);

Answer (score 2):

Your `doCountDown` method should check for the condition decrement till 0 in `for-loop`. i.e `i>=0`,

```
public static void doCountDown(int num){
    for(int i=num;i>=0;i--){
        System.out.println(i);
        waitASec();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the middle part of your for loop, i<=num. This is the part that determines when the loop will terminate. This is saying that as long as i is less than or equal to num, the loop will continue. i starts equal to num, and at the end of each loop you decrease i by 1 (i--). So i will always be less than num, therefore your loop will continue forever.

Try using for(int i=num;i >= 0;i--) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Of course count down never end. Because `i <= num` always true. Change your logic with this;

```
public static void doCountDown(int num){
    for(int i=num;i>= 0;i--){
        System.out.println(i);
        waitASec();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got one small error in your for loop condition that's the source of your error, I revised your code a bit

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Code {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Count down how many seconds? ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    //sc.close();
    doCountDown(num);
    sc.close();//move here otherwise you might get null pointer exception
}
public static void doCountDown(int num){
    for(int i=num;i>=0;i--){//It should count down to zero (replaced num with 0)
        System.out.println(i);
        waitASec();
    }
}
private static void waitASec() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);//This approach better than java.util.Date
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```